# R subsetting 3d array and modifying specific values if three conditions met

Tags: r, arrays, tidyverse

I'm working with a 3-d array and attempting to replace specific values when three conditions are met, and it will cope with NA values, and it performs a new evaluation for each time the conditions are met.  I read somewhere that attempting to subset multiple dimension arrays in R was not a good idea.  Any comments/suggestions to overcome these issues is most welcome. Any solution using base R or tidyverse (or anything!) most welcome. Thx. J

Essentially, I'm trying to replace the 7's in the final row of the third "sheet", with 0, 50% of the time when the other conditions are met.

This is my attempt using an ifelse but it fails, think it might need to be a more sophisticated apply statement or something. Here is my MWE:

```
library(abind)
arr1 <- as.array (matrix (c (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                             1, 1, NA, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 8))

arr2 <- as.array (matrix (c (7, 5, 9, 1, 8, 4, 2, 3, 0, 8, 7, NA,
                             2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 8, 3, 3, 6, 8, 5), ncol = 8))

arr3 <- as.array (matrix (c (7, 5, 7, 1, 8, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 7,
                             2, 4, 5, 3, 2, NA, 8, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7), ncol = 8))

arrtot <- abind (arr1, arr2, arr3, along = 3)

## get the array to be changed
arrtot[dim(arrtot)[1], ,3]

arrtot[dim(arrtot)[1], ,3] <- ifelse(arrtot[dim(arrtot)[1], ,3] == 7 &
                               arrtot[dim(arrtot)[1], ,1] == 1 &
                               arrtot[dim(arrtot)[1], ,2] >= 5,
                               function (x) rbinom(1,1,0.5) * 7,
                               "original value unchanged")
```

Although there are several possible solutions, because of the random function, one possible correct solution would look like this where the two 7's that meet the conditions are modified to become zeros.

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1   NA    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1   NA    0    0    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    7    1    2    8    2    3    8    6
[2,]    5    8    3    7    4    2    3    8
[3,]    9    4    0   NA    6    8    3    5

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    7    1    2    8    2    3    8    6
[2,]    5    8    3    7    4    2    3    8
[3,]    0    7    6    7    5   NA    4    0
```

Comment: Hi Jim, could you clarify what the actual question is? Your code is working, right? Also, why the need for the extra package? You could use `array(c(...), dim = c(3,8,3))`.

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't, throws an error, think it needs to be more sophisticated in, at least the rbinom calculation.  I've tried all kinds of apply statements and other stuff but not got it to work correctly. Thx.